# Add a customField to ContentVersion

Tags: soql, notes, jsforce

TLDR: How do I retrieve a ContentVersion Object by customfield (jsforce or SOQL) and then how would I then populate that customfield?

More below:

I need a way to keep track of notes between two systems.
I do not seem able to add a custom field to notes.
I thought of noteTags except, each note will have a separate ID and 10,000+ noteTags doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Then, the option from a colleague was to add a custom field to the content version of a note.

Pardon my iterations, but I am working on this concurrent to this question being "abroad".

If I create a new note with JSforce, I then get a return value of that new notes ID & URL. Just fine. I can then get that notes most current ContentVersion Object. Then I need to add content a custom field to that ContentVersion object... Along the lines of this path:

```
// Conn = Connection to salesforce, objHandle is the Salesforce Record ID, noteContent is the content of the record, noteTitle is the title of the record.
  async function getSalesForceObject(conn, objHandle, noteContent, noteTitle) {
    try {
      await conn.sobject("ContentNote").create({ Content : noteContent, Title: noteTitle })
        .then((result) => {
          conn.sobject("ContentDocumentLink").create({ ContentDocumentId : result.id, LinkedEntityId: objHandle, ShareType: "V" }, function(err, ret) {
            if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
            console.log("Created Linked record id : " + ret.id);
          });
    });
    } catch(err) {
       //etc
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_fields.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Sure David. I would say:  is [one](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#crud).  [Another](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) not particular explicit syntax. Possibly I'll sort through it before an answer comes, but I appreciate the comment.

Comment: I've been struggling quite mightily though to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce the [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm) looks as in the below ERD diagram. `ContentNote` and `ContentVersion` are related with `Id-ContentDocumentId` as mentiond in the picture.

[image]

To update a CustomField in the `ContentVersion` you can follow the below steps.

1 - Get the Id of the `ContentVersion` with the help of `ContentNote` Id.

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '<Id of ContentNote>'
```

2 - Now update the `ContentVersion` with the CustomField Value. The below snippet is from [jsforce documentation](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#crud).

```
// Single record update (Documentation)
conn.sobject("ContentVersion").update({ 
  Id : '<ContentVersion Id from the previous step>',
  CustomField__c : '<Value of the CustomField>'
}, function(err, ret) {
  if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
  console.log('Updated Successfully : ' + ret.id);
  // ...
});
```